# loading photos and details of a place using google places api

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am displaying image of a place  along with its details using image view and text view which works fine ,when i select a place which has image,but when i select a place with no image my app crashes. If there is no image then i want to only display the details of place but it doesnt....Help would be appreciated .

here is my activity

```
package com.example.dell.Swing;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacePhotoMetadata;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlacePhotoMetadataResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
     import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
    import com.uber.sdk.android.core.UberSdk;
    import com.uber.sdk.android.rides.RideParameters;
    import com.uber.sdk.android.rides.RideRequestButton;
    import com.uber.sdk.core.auth.Scope;
    import com.uber.sdk.rides.client.SessionConfiguration;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Random;

    public class aarakuhotels extends AppCompatActivity {
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
RideRequestButton requestButton;
TextView placeNameText;
   ImageView image;
TextView placeAddressText,placeemailtext,placelocaletext,placephonetext;
WebView attributionText;
Button getPlaceButton;
private final static int MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
private final static int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aarakuhotels);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                }
            })
            .build();

    requestPermission();
    SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId("wd9fPCpvtObmPOHBogaVdicLZW5Cos1K") //This is necessary
            .setRedirectUri("YOUR_REDIRECT_URI") //This is necessary if you'll be using implicit grant
            .build();
```

//This is a convenience method and will set the default config to be used in other components without passing it directly.

```
      UberSdk.initialize(config);


    placeNameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hotelname);
    placeAddressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hoteladdress);
    placeemailtext =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    placelocaletext =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.locale);
    placephonetext =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hotelsimage);
   // attributionText = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.attribution);
    getPlaceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gethotels);
    getPlaceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            try {
                Intent intent = builder.build(aarakuhotels.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}

private void requestPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This app requires location permissions to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(aarakuhotels.this, data);
            //Log.d("TAG",data.toString()); wait check karru ok
            Log.d("TAG",place.toString());
            final String placeId = place.getId();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    PlacePhotoMetadataResult result = Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getPlacePhotos(mGoogleApiClient, placeId).await();


                    if (result != null && result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer photoMetadataBuffer = result.getPhotoMetadata();

                //getting error here when i select a place with no photo and app crashes  --> PlacePhotoMetadata photo = photoMetadataBuffer.get(0);

                        final Bitmap locationimg = photo.getPhoto(mGoogleApiClient).await()
                                .getBitmap();

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                image.setImageBitmap(locationimg);
                            }
                        });


                    }
                }
            }).start();



           // Picasso.with(this).load("https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-_jVRD4o6K20/VrAgjefDtCI/AAAAAAABoTw/TH6pNjEcU-MelyMU8ZzLikO1HVpMyHDPQCJkC/s544-k-no/").into(image);
            placeNameText.setText("Name:"+place.getName());
            placephonetext.setText("Phone:"+place.getPhoneNumber());
            placeemailtext.setText("Website:"+place.getWebsiteUri());
            placelocaletext.setText("Rating:"+place.getRating());
            placeAddressText.setText("Address:"+place.getAddress());
           // if (place.getAttributions() == null) {
             //   attributionText.loadData("no attribution", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UFT-8");
            //} else {
              //  attributionText.loadData(place.getAttributions().toString(), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UFT-8");
            //}
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the Problem I replaced Threads with normal code...Worked